# How to load correctly a partial view in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In my mvc project i have a controller with the following actions:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new List<Product>());
    }
```

The corresponding index view render a partial view with the master grid:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<TbbModels.Domain.Product>
@Html.Partial("_ProdutoMasterGrid", Model)
```

This partial view have a submit button and a grid. The client needs to put some data in the form and submit it to that action:

```
 public ActionResult _ProdutoMasterGrid(string param)
    {
        return PartialView("_ProdutoMasterGrid",
        repository.Compare(param).ToList());
    }
```

But than i get the grid without the layout. How can i return a partial view with the layout?

Comment: If you call a partial view from a main view, You will get the layout, as you are doing here in the index page. But if you directly call a partial view from controller, It will be rendered but it has no idea of wat the layout(main view) must be. So you get a empty page as layout.

Answer (score 1):

You should explicitly return the correct view:

```
public ActionResult _ProdutoMasterGrid(string param)
{
    return View("Index",
    repository.Compare(param).ToList());
}
```

This ensures that when you do a post to this action, it returns the index view. I'm supposing here that `repository.Compare` return a `List<Product>` as well, since the type needs to match.